# How to view list of subscriptions in Google reader app?

Tags: google-reader

Is there any way to view the list of my blog subscriptions in Google reader? Currently it is showing "no subscriptions". Is this a bug?

Answer (score 3):

On the main screen of the app press the `Menu` button and select `Show all`. You should see a list of all your subscriptions below the `SUBSCRIPTIONS` heading, with unread items showing in bold and the unread count to the right. It should look similar to this:

[image: Main screen of Google Reader App]

If you don't see anything listed there, you might want to double check the account you're using with the app by pressing the `Menu` button, and going to the `Accounts` option. There you can select your Google account, and check if syncing is enabled for Google Reader.

Answer (score 0):

Does it say "**You have no subscriptions with unread items.**"? If not, then you may need to synchronise with your Google Account, or add some feeds manually.

If you've synchronised with your Google Account, and/or have added feeds, you should be able to press `Menu > Show all`
This should display all of your subscriptions, whether they have new items or not. To go back to updated only: `Menu > Show updated`